# Magento 1.9.3 : Product custom options and product attribute price in cart, checkout page, invoice and admin

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, custom-options, invoice

Please check following link:

https://www.superbuniforms.com/medical-lab-coat-women-sky-blue

Please check "Interested in Embroidery" checkbox. One product option's section open. Here, two options already selected("One time designing logo fee Rs. 300") and checked(Per Embroidery Logo Charges र 35.00). Now, add this product in cart and check in cart.

In cart section, product unit price in without selected options price. Product option's price is displaying separately. But added in subtotal. When you increase product quantity product price and Per Embroidery Logo Charges र 35.00 are increase with quantity but ("One time designing logo fee Rs. 300") is not increased.

One time logo desinging fee apply only one time for every product order but per embroidery logo charges increse with quantity. Means if any customer ordered 2 quantity of product and choose One time logo designing fee 300 and per embroidery logo charges 35 which already selected when click on "interested in embroidery" checkbox.

In cart section, need (product price* 2 quantity)+ 35*2 quantity) + (300*1)  = product subtotal

I need implement for Magento 1.9.3. How to do for Magento? Please suggest. Reference site is built in Opencart.

[image: product detail page]

[image: cart page]

Comment: Please reply any one on this question.

Comment: have you found any solution for magento? i have need also need help for this.

Comment: This should help https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html